# How do I remove the left-hand side padding on this jsfiddle?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble with my HTML/CSS, there is some kind of padding on the left hand side of the page which means the content is not perfectly centered. When reducing the window width this padding is causing the browser to use a dreaded horizontal scrollbar! Would anybody be able to show me where I've gone wrong? The jsfiddle is:

https://jsfiddle.net/1faj9xt5/

HTML:

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Simple Portfolio Theme</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/a61938b57c.js"></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="outer">
      <div class="middle">
        <div class="inner">

          <div class="container">
            <section id="header">
              <header>
                <span class="avatar"><img src="images/avatar.jpg" alt="" /></span>
                <h1>Me</h1>
                <p>About Me</p>
              </header>

              <ul class="icons">
                <li><a href="#" title="Twitter" class="fa-twitter">Twitter</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Instagram" class="fa-instagram">Instagram</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Facebook" class="fa-facebook">Facebook</a></li>
              </ul>
            </section>

            <!--start portfolio-->
            <section id="portfolio">
              <div class="row">
                <!---start row-->

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                  <!--start element 1-->
                  <div class="thumbnail shadow up-hover">
                    <img src="http://emant.altervista.org/ext/tic.jpg" />
                    <div class="cust-caption">
                      <a href="https://codepen.io/Em-Ant/full/QbRyqq"><h3 class="stm-font">Test Title</h3></a>
                      <p>Test description. </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!--end element 1-->

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                  <!--start element 2-->
                  <div class="thumbnail shadow up-hover">
                    <img src="http://emant.altervista.org/ext/tic.jpg" />
                    <div class="cust-caption">
                      <a href="https://codepen.io/Em-Ant/full/vObzWm"><h3 class="stm-font">Test Titlek</h3></a>
                      <p>Test description. </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!--end element 2-->

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                  <!--start element 3-->
                  <div class="thumbnail shadow up-hover">
                    <img src="http://emant.altervista.org/ext/tic.jpg" />
                    <div class="cust-caption">
                      <a href="https://codepen.io/Em-Ant/full/OVabRP"><h3 class="stm-font">Test Title</h3></a>
                      <p>Test description. </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!--end element 3-->

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                  <!--start element 4-->
                  <div class="thumbnail shadow up-hover">
                    <img src="http://emant.altervista.org/ext/tic.jpg" />
                    <div class="cust-caption">
                      <a href="https://codepen.io/Em-Ant/full/jPQqwB"><h3 class="stm-font">Test Title</h3></a>
                      <p>Test description. </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!--end element 4-->

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                  <!--start element 5-->
                  <div class="thumbnail shadow up-hover">
                    <img src="http://emant.altervista.org/ext/tic.jpg" />
                    <div class="cust-caption">
                      <a href="https://codepen.io/Em-Ant/full/WvPNPM"><h3 class="stm-font">Test Title</h3></a>
                      <p>Test description. </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!--end element 5-->

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                  <!--start element 6-->
                  <div class="thumbnail shadow up-hover">
                    <img src="http://emant.altervista.org/ext/tic.jpg" />
                    <div class="cust-caption">
                      <a href="https://codepen.io/Em-Ant/full/KpEWdR"><h3 class="stm-font">Test Title</h3></a>
                      <p>Test description. </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!---end row-->
            </section>
            <!--end portfolio-->
          </div>
          <!--end container-->
        </div>
      </div>
      <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
      <script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>



      <script src="js/index.js"></script>




  </body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
    @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Share+Tech+Mono);
  .thumbnail {
    max-width: 500px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }

  .shadow {
    box-shadow: 7px 7px 7px #666;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    top: 0;
  }

  .cust-caption {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.8);
    padding: 10px;
    color: #ddd;
    margin: 5px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 90%;
    margin: 5px;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }

  .stm-font {
    font-family: 'Share Tech Mono', monospace;
  }

  .color-hover:hover {
    color: #337AB7;
  }

  .up-hover:hover {
    top: -5px;
    box-shadow: 15px 15px 15px #777;
  }

  .cust-caption a {
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black;
  }

  .outer {
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .middle {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }

  .inner {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
  /* header */

  #header {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 27em;
    padding: 4.5em 3em 3em 3em;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: default;
    opacity: 0.95;
    text-align: center;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease, -moz-transform 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease, -webkit-transform 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease, -ms-transform 1s ease;
    transition: opacity 1s ease, transform 1s ease;
  }

  #header .avatar {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  }

  #header .avatar img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1.5em #ffffff;
  }

  #header .avatar:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: -3em;
    width: calc(100% + 6em);
    height: 1px;
    z-index: -1;
    background: #c8cccf;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #header {
      min-width: 0;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 4em 2em 2.5em 2em;
    }
    #header .avatar:before {
      left: -2em;
      width: calc(100% + 4em);
    }
  }

  #header .avatar {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  }

  #header .avatar img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1.5em #ffffff;
  }

  #header .avatar:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: -3em;
    width: calc(100% + 6em);
    height: 1px;
    z-index: -1;
    background: #c8cccf;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #header {
      min-width: 0;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 4em 2em 2.5em 2em;
    }
    #header .avatar:before {
      left: -2em;
      width: calc(100% + 4em);
    }
  }
  /* List */

  ol {
    list-style: decimal;
    margin: 0 0 1.5em 0;
    padding-left: 1.25em;
  }

  ol li {
    padding-left: 0.25em;
  }

  ul {
    list-style: disc;
    margin: 0 0 1.5em 0;
    padding-left: 1em;
  }

  ul li {
    padding-left: 0.5em;
  }

  ul.alt {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
  }

  ul.alt li {
    border-top: solid 1px #c8cccf;
    padding: 0.5em 0;
  }

  ul.alt li:first-child {
    border-top: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
  }

  ul.icons {
    cursor: default;
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-top: -0.675em;
  }

  ul.icons li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.675em 0.5em;
  }

  ul.icons li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 3.75em;
    height: 3.75em;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: solid 1px #c8cccf;
    line-height: 3.75em;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    text-indent: 3.75em;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }

  ul.icons li a:before {
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: none !important;
  }

  ul.icons li a:before {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 1.25px 0px 0px #c8cccf, -1.25px 0px 0px #c8cccf, 0px 1.25px 0px #c8cccf, 0px -1.25px 0px #c8cccf;
  }

  ul.icons li a:hover:before {
    text-shadow: 1.25px 0px 0px #ff7496, -1.25px 0px 0px #ff7496, 0px 1.25px 0px #ff7496, 0px -1.25px 0px #ff7496;
  }

  ul.icons li a:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    font-size: 1.85rem;
    line-height: inherit;
    text-align: center;
    text-indent: 0;
  }

  ul.icons li a:hover {
    border-color: #ff7496;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    ul.icons li a:before {
      font-size: 1.5rem;
    }
```

Comment: Addition: put the .stop() method before .slideDown() & .fadeOut()

Comment: Do you mean the padding on the `.container` class? That's native bootstrap

Comment: I don't see any horizontal scrollbar! on window resizing. Please be more specific.

Comment: Oh, that's weird... I'm not getting the scrollbar either in JSFiddle - Heres a screenshot of the behavior in my browser: https://i.imgur.com/rBeXdzh.png

Comment: On further inspection it seems to be a gap outside of the bootstrap .container class? See https://i.imgur.com/AJIJO5V.png for what I mean?